# How to enable additional schema in an embedded spring ldap server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

I am using Spring 4.3.10 with Spring security 3.2.9. I am trying to move our current setup to use an embedded ldap server, previously we deployed a custom server from a war file. I have successfully been able to setup the embedded ldap and load the ldif. 
However when I attempt any sort of modify request I run into an issue that I believe results from not having the NIS schema enabled as outlined similarly here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/pull/20

I do not have access to LdapTestUtils as we are down rev. This is the error I am getting:

```
 Caused by: javax.naming.directory.NoSuchAttributeException: [LDAP: error code 16 - NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for     Modify Request
        Object : 'cn=userName_1544009893937,ou=6630d92e-d7f4-4b1f-9572-eb0488124123,ou=orgs,ou=oec,dc=opsource,dc=net'
            Modification[0]
                Operation :  add
                Modification
    homeDirectory: /opt/workspace/orgs/6/66/6630d92e-d7f4-4b1f-9572-eb0488124123
            Modification[1]
                Operation :  replace
                Modification
    userPassword: '0x7B 0x53 0x53 0x48 0x41 0x7D 0x46 0x69 0x50 0x66 0x6D 0x50 0x32 0x34 0x57 0x47 ...'
: attributeType w/ OID 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 not registered!]; remaining name 'cn=userName_1544009893937,ou=6630d92e-d7f4-4b1f-9572-eb0488124123,ou=orgs'
```

1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 maps to the homeDirectory attribute in the NIS schema. My understanding of ldap is fairly basic. Is there any way to enable this schema via the ldif or is there an alternative approach I could try?